# Set style using CSS / JavaScript to element which becomes visible later

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a tabbed layout using Bootstrap 4. The second tab has a table which is containing black cells at times. I have a script which runs on document.load that fixes the height of table cells that are blank.

This script is not working on this tab tables, because initially they are in a hidden state and the height that get's captured in my script becomes zero.

I want to to make the blank cell height same as the non-blank cells. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The best help you can give us, if you wish for our help, is to post all relevant code. That will increase your chance of getting not only more answers, but also answer that will fix your problem

Comment: Yeah please provide a code snippet with all your code.

Comment: Thanks guys for your quick response. I just used :hidden selector to detect all hidden tabs and modified the DOM children table rows. That worked! Yay! Thanks again.